# pgfplots sample colors from colorbar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I would like to get the color definition from a sample of colors in a pgfplots colormap using for example the RGB model. When I choose `colormap/bluered` with `colorbar style={samples=10}` I need to have the xcolor definition of those particular colors to plot different curves. Is there an automatic way to generate these color specifications from the colormap definition?

Comment: @Jake I would like to have the color values and show a sampled color bar with a scale. I will add an example to the question.

Comment: @Jake That's right, each plot has the same color in the whole domain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a colour from the colormap available as `mapped color` by calling the macro `\pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{<value>}`, where `<value>` is a number between 0 and 1000 that is mapped linearly into the current color map.

In order to use different colours for different plots, this macro needs to be called within `execute at begin plot visualization`, otherwise all the plots end up with the same colour:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colormap/hot,
    domain=0:360,
    colorbar sampled,
    colorbar style={samples=6},
    point meta min=0,
    point meta max=10
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,5}{
\addplot [
    execute at begin plot visualization={%
        \pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{\numexpr#1*200-100\relax}
    },
    mapped color,
    thick
] {#1*sin(x)};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get this error when I compile this example on Texlive 2012:! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor ...formedrange 
                                                  ] [1.0] {#1} {\pgfkeysvalu...

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro: What version of PGFPlots are you using?

Comment: pgfplots 2011/12/29 v1.5.1

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro: Ah, yes, that's pretty dated. I would recommend updating to the current version (1.8)

Comment: Thanks, however the pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor does not work for me when I read the data coordinates from a file like
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {datafile.dat};

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro: What error message do you get? Could you edit your question to include the code for a minimal example that shows the problem?

Comment: I have edited the answer showing the resulting figure when the data are read from a file.

Comment: The code of this answer does not seem to work anymore. Anyway, how can I make sure that the mapped color of every plot is also used for the corresponding legend entry?