# Change color of \addplot in a \foreach loop (pgfplots)

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

I have this `pgfplots`  plot and I want every single graph to have a different color. A gradient from red to blue or something else (`m=2` should be `red`, `m=11` should be `blue` and all the other `m` should be between this).

I need this to work even when I change the amount of graphs.

I already tried to transfer the code lines from this example, but I can't get it working: [Plotting a graph with several values of a parameter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238266/plotting-a-graph-with-several-values-of-a-parameter)

The minimum working example is added below.

Thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{
    gainplot/.style={
        axis x line*=box,
        xmax=10,
        xmin=0.1,
        xmode=log,
        width=14cm,
        xlabel=$F_\textup{x}$,
        xticklabel style={yshift=-0.2cm,},
        xtick={0.1,1.0,10.0},
        xticklabels={{$0.1$},{$1.0$},{$10.0$}},
        axis y line*=box,
        ymax=3,
        ymin=0,
        ymode=normal,
        height=7cm,
        ylabel=$K$,
        yticklabel style={xshift=-0.2cm,},
        ytick={0,1,2,3 },
        yticklabels={{$0$},{$1$},{$2$},{$3$}},
        grid = both,
        grid style={line width=0.2pt,},
        legend style={
            font=\scriptsize,
            at={(0.5,1.03)},
            anchor=south,
            draw=none,
        },
        legend columns=5,
    },
    gainplot/.belongs to family=/pgfplots/scale,
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gaincurve}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{%
        (x^2*(#2-1)/(sqrt((#2*x^2-1)^2+x^2*(x^2-1)^2*(#2-1)^2*#1^2)))
    }%
}

\tikzstyle{gaincurvestyle}=[
    smooth,
    %thick,
    mark=none,
    domain=0.1:10,
    samples=100,
]


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[gainplot]
\foreach \m in {2,3,...,11}{
    \addplot[gaincurvestyle,red]{gaincurve(0.2,\m)}; %%% Here help is needed.
    \addlegendentryexpanded{$m=\m$}
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Placeholder.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is  a similar question at the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170221/pgfplots-line-colors, or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126100/pgfplots-sample-colors-from-colorbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `\edef` trick mentioned in the `pgfplots` manual, combined with `evaluate` in the `\foreach`, and the `red!<value>!blue` color syntax.

If you want to normalize based on the values of the loop, you can use

```
\foreach [evaluate=\m as \redfrac using (\m-<minimum>)*100/(<maximum>-<minimum>)] ...
```

and then set the color of the plot to `red!\redfrac!blue`. For example, if the lowest value in the loop is 2 and the highest is 11, as in your example, you use `(\m-2)*100/(11-2)`.

If you instead want to normalize based on the index of the loop, you can do

```
\foreach [count=\i from 0,evaluate=\i as \redfrac using \i*100/<number of elements in list>)] ...
```

For example, if you're looping over a list of 15 values, use `\i*100/15`. In both cases, it's just a matter of normalizing a value so that it runs from 0 to 100.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{
    gainplot/.style={
        axis x line*=box,
        xmax=10,
        xmin=0.1,
        xmode=log,
        width=14cm,
        xlabel=$F_\textup{x}$,
        xticklabel style={yshift=-0.2cm,},
        xtick={0.1,1.0,10.0},
        xticklabels={{$0.1$},{$1.0$},{$10.0$}},
        axis y line*=box,
        ymax=3,
        ymin=0,
        ymode=normal,
        height=7cm,
        ylabel=$K$,
        yticklabel style={xshift=-0.2cm,},
        ytick={0,1,2,3 },
        yticklabels={{$0$},{$1$},{$2$},{$3$}},
        grid = both,
        grid style={line width=0.2pt,},
        legend style={
            font=\scriptsize,
            at={(0.5,1.03)},
            anchor=south,
            draw=none,
        },
        legend columns=5,
    },
    gainplot/.belongs to family=/pgfplots/scale,
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gaincurve}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{%
        (x^2*(#2-1)/(sqrt((#2*x^2-1)^2+x^2*(x^2-1)^2*(#2-1)^2*#1^2)))
    }%
}

\tikzstyle{gaincurvestyle}=[
    smooth,
    %thick,
    mark=none,
    domain=0.1:10,
    samples=100,
]


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[gainplot]
\foreach [evaluate=\m as \redfrac using (\m-2)*100/(11-2)] \m in {2,3,...,11}{
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[gaincurvestyle,red!\redfrac!blue]{gaincurve(0.2,\m)};
    \noexpand\addlegendentry{$m=\m$}}
    \temp
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Placeholder.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Swap `red` and `blue` in the `\addplot` to change the direction of the gradient.

Comment: I have a question yet again. In your solution the color gradient depends on the value of \m. But if I have something like this {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6, 0.8,1.0,1.5,2.0,3.0,5.0}  for \m, all graphs are almost blue. Just a little red is visible.

Comment: Is it possible, that the color gradient depends on the amount of graphs? So the first graph is blue and the last one is red. I think I would call it fixed step width (ignoring the values).

Comment: @Benjamin1956 Sorry, didn't explain that. I had `evaluate=\m as \redfrac using (\m-2)*100/(11-2)`, where `2` is the lowest value of `\m` and `11` is the highest value. You need to change those numbers accordingly, so e.g. `evaluate=\m as \redfrac using (\m-0.1)*100/(5-0.1)`.

Comment: Can't you use `\pgfplotsextra{...}` instead of the `\edef` trick

Comment: Ok, I already got this, but this still doesn't make any changes:Try to replace this with yours:\begin{axis}[gainplot,ylabel={$K(Q,m=\m,F_\textup{x})$}]
\def\m{8.000}
\foreach [evaluate=\Q as \redfrac using (\Q-0.1)*100/(5-0.1)] \Q in {0.100,0.125,0.150,0.175,0.200,0.250,0.300,0.400,0.600, 0.800,1.000,1.500,2.000,3.000,5.000}{
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[gaincurvestyle,red!\redfrac!blue]{gaincurve(\Q,\m)};
    \noexpand\addlegendentry{$Q=\Q$}}
    \temp
}
\end{axis}

Comment: I tried to edit your answer to show what I mean. But this needs to be reviewed first.

Comment: @Benjamin1956 Ah, just not me thinking clearly. You'd want to normalize based on the index, not the value. So with 15 values in the loop, `[count=\i from 0,evaluate=\i as \redfrac using \i*100/15)]`

Comment: @Benjamin1956 I rejected the edit. I don't know how to get the number of values in the list automatically, though there might well be a way.

Comment: It is okay for me, to count the number of values and insert it manually.

Comment: @daleif I've never used `\pgfplotsextra`, so I don't know.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. One more question (but this hasn't directly to do with the question): Do you know, if it's possible to format the numbers in the legend to precision=3 and fixed zerofill?

Comment: @Benjamin1956 And as such it would be better to ask a new question, but try `\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3]{\m}` instead of just `\m`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Hi, I have another question regarding my pgfplots. Maybe you have an answer for this, too? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353956/arrange-multiple-2d-addplot-graphs-as-3d-surface-diagram-in-pgfplots

Comment: I am struggling with `foreach`, so I would be grateful if you could explain to me the meaning of `evaluate=\m as \redfrac using (\m-2)*100/(11-2)] \m in {2,3,...,11}`. Thanks

Comment: @Diaa For each step in the loop, the expression (m-2)*etc. is evaluated, and the result stored in \redfrac.