# Changing the color and labels of a plot in a loop in pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, loops

I’m trying to plot a the first few functions in a sequence of functions. For now my code looks like that:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines = left,
                    xlabel = $x$, 
                    ylabel = $y$,
                    xmin = 0,
                    xmax=10,
                    ymin=-0.1,
                    ymax = 0.4,
                    legend pos = outer north east];
            \addplot[domain=0:10, samples=100, color=gray, dashed]{sqrt(2)/2*exp(-pi/4)};
            \addlegendentry{$\sup_{x\in I}\card{f_n}$}
            \foreach \n in {1,2,...,7}{
\addplot [domain=0:10, samples=500, color=red]{sin(deg(\n*x))*exp(-\n*x)};
}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

But as you can see in the code each plot is red. Is there a way so that each function is plotted with a different color while still plotting them with a loop ? In the same vein can I add a legend entry for each function the loop like f_1(x), f_2(x), ..., f_7(x) ?
Changing the color for each plot is discussed here [Change color of \addplot in a \foreach loop (pgfplots)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353789/change-color-of-addplot-in-a-foreach-loop-pgfplots) but I couldn’t get what they did working, I don’t actually understand everything (ie what does \edef or \noexpand or \temp do) and I’m not looking necessarily at having a gradient of colors, I’m ok with random colors as long as they’re different.
I havent used pgfplots for a while I’m not quite sure how to go about any of this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `foreach` loops in `pgfplots` you have to add `noexpand` for each expression. With the `evaluate` comand you can calculate a value according to the loop variable.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=left,
            xlabel=$x$, 
            ylabel=$y$,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=10,
            ymin=-0.1,
            ymax=0.4,
            legend pos=outer north east];
            
            \addplot[
            domain=0:10, 
            samples=100, 
            color=gray, 
            dashed,
            ]{sqrt(2)/2*exp(-pi/4)};
            
%           \addlegendentry{$\sup_{x\in I}\card{f_n}$} %<-causing some error 
            \foreach [evaluate=\i as \n using (\i)*100/(7)] \i in {1,2,...,7} {%
                \edef\temp{%
                    \noexpand
                        \addplot[
                        domain=0:10, 
                        samples=500,
                        color=red!\n!blue,
                        smooth,
                        ]
                        {sin(deg(\i*x))*exp(-\i*x)};
                    }\temp
                }       
        \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks this works well! What is still unclear is what exactly do the commands \edef and \temp do ?

Comment: As I understood it, you define the plot as `temp` and 'plot' it after the loop. You can try redefine `\temp` (e.g., `\test`, ...) and call it before and after the loop.

Comment: BTW, what does `\card` in the legend do?

Comment: oh yeah that's a macro I picked up from an old prof I had, in my preamble I usually have `\newcommand{\card}[1]{\left | #1 \right |}`